# Вывод переменных js

Tags: javascript

Есть проблема.
Допустим есть переменная `var my = 33`.
Есть код:

```
var aloha = {
id: my,
type: 'mytype',
lvalue: my, };
```

Нужно чтобы в браузере вместо `my` выводилось `33`.
Пробовал разные способы и экспериментировал, но ничего не получается.

Когда у меня переменная в `php`, я просто делаю вставку `<?=$my;?>` и все.
А вот когда значение в переменной `js`, у меня возникает такая проблема, помогите пожалуйста.

Какой результат я хочу получить:
Чтобы в теле документа было `id: 33` при просмотре кода в браузере должно быть как на изображении ниже, только вместо `my` - её значение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы получилось вот так при просмотре кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По просьбе отвечающих - оригинальный код:

```
var google_tag_params = {
  dynx_itemid: idsGoogleTag,
  dynx_pagetype: 'conversion',
  dynx_totalvalue: totalGoogleTag,
};
```

В переменных `idsGoogleTag` и `totalGoogleTag` хранятся нужные мне значения.

Comment: Из вашего вопроса не видно сути проблемы. Куда именно вы хотите вывести переменную? В тело HTML-документа?

Comment: да. чтоб в теле документа было id: 33

Comment: покажите код, в котором у вас при выводе получается `my`, а не `33`

Comment: в js не получается. когда есть переменная в php то вот так var aloha = {
id: <?=$my;?>,
type: 'mytype',
lvalue: <?=$my;?>, };

Comment: это возможно только если script генерировать самостоятельно

Comment: можно поподробнее?

Comment: кроме того, совсем непонятно **зачем** это нужно. Яваскрипт вполне позволяет использовать переменные в объектах

Comment: это нужно для GA. (google analytics)

Comment: Добавляйте пример с GA, который не работает с переменной

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42201/discussion-between-grundy-and-mydls1).

Comment: После некоторых консультаций, мне обьяснили, что так реализовать нельзя. Был немного изменен, теперь считываются значения. Всем Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не проблема, `var aloha` - это объект, чтобы `my` стало равно `33` нужно написать:

```
aloha.id = 33
```

Comment: да, я понимаю, но мне нельзя менять свойства обьекта id type и т.п (  нужно чтоб получилось вот так, только через js  id: <?=$my?>    что эквивалентно id: 33 .((

Comment: а свойство lvalue можно менять, просто если нельзя менять объект то тогда зачем он вообще нужен в этом примере

Comment: нет нельзя. в оригинале это обьект google , после : я должен передать значения. свойства менять нельзя, т.к он не пройдет валидацию на входе

Answer (score 0):

C jQuery:

```
$('куда вставить').html(aloha.id)
```

можна и без jQuery:

```
var myBlock = document.getElementById('куда вставить');
myBlock.innerHTML = aloha.id;
```

Comment: я добавил изображение.

Comment: Ответ оффтопик. jQuery не указан ни в тексте вопроса ни в метках. Укажите, хотя бы у себя в ответе когда работает такая конструкция

Comment: можна и без jQuery, var myBlock = document.getElementById('куда вставить'); myBlock.innerHTML = aloha.id;

Comment: `html`-то тут зачем(((

Comment: @tutankhamun прям полиция нравов, он же указал что с jquery, не вижу проблемы. Без jquery сейчас пишут только jquery :)

Comment: @KeyGenQt А то :) А проблема есть. В первой версии ответа был только код, что само по себе не хорошо. Ну и кроме того, на сайте сложилась тенденция: если вопрос идет с меткой js и без всякого указания на jq - ответы с jq сразу уходят в минусы

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
my=33;
document.write("\u003Cscript>var aloha = {\nid: "+my+",\ntype: 'mytype',\nlvalue: "+my+", };\n\u003C/script>");
</script>
```

Тут как смотреть в браузере, если инспектором, то код заменён.